# Stomp Client not receiving messages from Spring

Tags: spring-boot, websocket, stomp

My configuration class is:

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
public class WebSocketConfig implements WebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry config) {
        config.enableSimpleBroker("/topic");
        config.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/app");
    }

    @Override
    public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
        registry
            .addEndpoint("/websocket")
            .setAllowedOrigins("*")
            .setHandshakeHandler(new CustomHandshakeHandler());

        registry
            .addEndpoint("/websocket")
            .setAllowedOrigins("*")
            .setHandshakeHandler(new CustomHandshakeHandler())
            .withSockJS();
    }

}
```

I have the following controller for the websocket on spring boot

```java
@Controller
public class WebSocketController {

    @Autowired
    private WebSocketService webSocketService;

    @MessageMapping("/mran")
    @SendToUser("/topic/mran")
    public String reply(@Payload String message, Principal user) {
        
        System.out.println("Received message: " + message);

        return "Hello " + message;
    }
}
```

And the following code on client:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sockjs-client@1/dist/sockjs.min.js"></script>
        <script src="./stomp.js"></script>
        <title>Document</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    
        <button onclick="sendMessage()">Click here to send a message</button>
    
        <script>
            var sock = new SockJS('http://localhost:8080/websocket');
            var stompClient = Stomp.over(sock);
            stompClient.connect({}, function(frame) {
    
                    stompClient.subscribe('/topic/mran', function (msg) {
                        console.log(msg)
                    });
    
            });
    
    
            function sendMessage() {
                stompClient.send('/app/mran', {}, JSON.stringify({'name': 'teste'}))
            }
    
        </script>
    
    </body>
</html>
```

On the spring I'm receiving the messages from the client, but on the client I'm not receiving the messages from the server, I've researched a lot and checked my "routes" but I didn't find any error. Btw, on the console output I've the following (after sending a message to server):

[image]

So why the messages are not being showed on the console?

Answer (score 0):

I found what is going wrong with my client, to receive a message from the server I've to subscribe to the channel `/user/topic/mran` this is due the fact that I'm using the annotation `@SendToUser` on SpringBoot. An example of the client working is:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sockjs-client@1/dist/sockjs.min.js"></script>
    <script src="./stomp.js"></script>
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>

    <button onclick="sendMessage()">Click here to send a message</button>

    <script>
        var sock = new SockJS('http://localhost:8080/websocket');
        var stompClient = Stomp.over(sock);
        stompClient.connect({}, function(frame) {

                stompClient.subscribe('/user/topic/mran', function (msg) {
                    console.log(msg)
                });

        });


        function sendMessage() {
            stompClient.send('/app/mran', {}, JSON.stringify({'name': 'teste'}))
        }

    </script>

</body>
</html>
```